# How to partition $[a,b]$ into $m$ equal sub-intervals and count the number of sub-intervals that intersect with a subset of $[a,b]$?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-request, sets, broken-code

Suppose we have a subset of $[a,b]$, where $a=0$ and $b=1$, such as

$$A_1=\left\{\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{2^y}+\frac{1}{2^z}:x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,1]$$

Which is a subset of $[0,1]$

If we partition $[a,b]$ into $m$ sub-intervals of equal length, where in this case $a=0$ and $b=1$, how do we count the number of sub-intervals which interesect with $A_1$?

**How do we generalize this for any $A_1$? Such that the function inside the brackets in the definition of the set is arbitrary?**

Take for example:

$$A_1=\left\{\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{xy}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}:x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,1]$$

(Note the number sub-intervals that intersect with $A_1$ should be less than $m$)

## Attempt

```
generateA[c_Integer] := 
 Select[Union@
   Flatten[Table[
     1/2^x + 1/2^y + 1/2^z, {x, 1, c}, {y, x, c}, {z, y, c}]], 
  0 <= # <= 1 &]
```

This generates $A_1$.

```
P[m_] := Interval /@ Partition[Subdivide[m], 2, 1]
```

This takes the $m$ sub-intervals, of equal length, of $[a,b]$

```
Total[Table[
Sign[Total[
Boole[Table[
IntervalMemberQ[P[m][[s]], generateA[100][[g]]], {g, 1, 
Length[generateA[5]]}]]]], {s, 1, m}]]
```

This shows whether each element, for every `c`-value of $A_1$, belongs to one of the $m$ sub-intervals. If one element is in the $m$ sub-intervals, it is counted using `boole`; and, if multiple elements are counted, we add them up and using `Sign` to convert them to `1`. If no elements are in the $m$ sub-intervals, the `boole` of all elements are zero and the sum of these `boole`s is zero, hence the `Sign` is zero. We add the `Signs` of all sub-intervals to get the total number of sub-intervals intersecting with $A_1$.

The problem is as $m \to \infty$, it takes too much time to calculate all the sub-intervals that intersect with $A_1$. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

`BinCounts` is a bit of overkill but still efficient.  Beware the bins in the partition are disjoint.  I assumed the number `1` was meant to be in the last bin of the partition.

```
Block[{m = 1000},
  With[{seq = 2^Range[-Ceiling@Log2@N@m - 2., -1.]},
   Total[#] + 1 - Last[#] &@Unitize@BinCounts[
      Flatten@Outer[Plus, seq, seq, seq],
      {0., 1., 1./m}]
   ]] // RepeatedTiming

(*  {0.00024, 170}  *)
```

Floating-point is faster than exact integer/rational arithmetic, but you have to worry about round-off error.  Once `m` gets to `10^15` or `16^16`, we need to switch to arbitrary-precision:

```
Block[{m = 10^16},
  With[{prec = 
     If[# > MachinePrecision, #, MachinePrecision] &@Log10[10. m]},
   With[{seq = 2^Range[-Ceiling@Log2@N@m - SetPrecision[2, prec], -1]},
    Total[#] + 1 - Last[#] &@Unitize@BinCounts[
       Flatten@Outer[Plus, seq, seq, seq],
       {0, SetPrecision[1, prec], N[1/m, prec]}]
    ]]] // RepeatedTiming

(*  {0.29, 25024}  *)
```

Here's an exact rational-number computation:

```
Block[{m = 10^16},
  With[{k = Ceiling@Log2@N@m + 2},
   Total[#] + 1 - Last[#] &@Unitize@BinCounts[
      Total[Tuples[2^Range[-k, -1], 3], {2}],
      {0, 1, 1/m}]
   ]] // RepeatedTiming

(*  {0.646, 25024}  *)
```

If the end-points are supposed to belong to each bin, then this would need adjustment (and the bins would not, strictly speaking, form a partition).

P.S. I tried it with `Tuples` instead of `Outer`, but it was slower, especially for large `m`.

```
With[{k = Ceiling@Log2@N@m + 2.},
 Total[#] + 1 - Last[#] &@Unitize@BinCounts[
    Total[Tuples[2^Range[-k, -1.], 3], {2}],
    {0., 1., 1./m}]
 ]
```

P.P.S. Another way, with `Floor`:

```
Block[{m = 10^16},
  With[{prec = 
     If[# > MachinePrecision, #, MachinePrecision] &@Log10[1000. m]},
   With[{seq = 2^Range[-Ceiling@Log2@N@m - SetPrecision[2, prec], -1]},
    Total[
     UnitStep[m - #] UnitStep[#] &@DeleteDuplicates@Floor[
        m*Flatten@Outer[Plus, seq, seq, seq]
        ]
     ]
    ]]] // RepeatedTiming

(*  {0.269, 25024}  *)
```

Comment: In one of my questions I stated how we can generalize this to any set? What if we had $\left\{\frac{1}{c}:c\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,1]$? I wasn't able to work this out.

Comment: For example, what if the function inside the bracket in the definition of $A_1$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Suppose you have a function `f[x1_, x2_,..., xn_]` of `n` arguments.  Then you have to replace `seq` by `seq1`, `seq2`,..., `seqn`, where the sequences are of the form `Range[a1, b1]`, `Range[a2, b2]`,..., `Range[an, bn]` -- and hopefully you can work out the limits `a` and `b` for each range (they will depend on `f` and `m`).  Then replace `Flatten@Outer[Plus,...]` with `Flatten@Outer[f, seq1, seq2,..., seqk]`.  For $1/c$, `seq1 = Range[1, m+1]`. For a single-variable `f[x]`, one can replace `Flatten@Outer[..` by `f /@ seq1`.

Comment: Is it possible to write this out in your answer. I will accept it with +15 points.

Comment: ...... For example, what would happen if we took $A_1=\left\{\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}:x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,1]$.....Apologies I want to fully understand your code.

Comment: @RajanArak Are you able to figure out the ranges for `seq1` etc.? That's a mathematical problem, but things like `Reduce[0 <= (x^2 + x y + y^2)/(x + y) + Sqrt[2]/2 <= 1]` or `Reduce[0 <= (x^2 + x y + y^2)/(x + y) + Sqrt[2]/2 <= 1 && {x, y} \[Element] Integers]` or `Plot3D[(x^2 + x y + y^2)/(x + y) + Sqrt[2]/2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0, 1}}, PlotRange -> 2]` might help. (They indicate that $A_1$ is empty, which makes me think it's not a good example.